# Keep Getting "Invalid Syntax" on a simple line of code

Tags: python

```
print('hello world!')   
print('what is your name?')  #ask for their name
MyName = input()
print('It is good to meet you' + MyName)
print('The length of your name is: ')
print((len(MyName))
print('What is your age?') #ask for their age
MyAge = input()
print('You will be ' + str(int(MyAge) + 1) + ' in a year.')
```

I keep getting invalid syntax on the what is your age line. I do not know what is wrong with it. I checked to make sure I have the correct amount of parenthesis and apostrophes. Not sure what to do. I am learning of the Automate the boring stuff with python YT courses. Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: ```print((len(MyName))``` should be ```print(len(MyName))```.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the error. Usually the error has a pointer abour the line on which the error occured.

Answer (score 1):

You get invalid syntax because you had an open bracket, and switched lines without closing it.

`print((len(MyName))` should be `print(len(MyName))`

Comment: Ahhh! Thanks a ton. Looked over the lines multiples times and somehow did not catch that.

Answer (score 0):

you added an extra parentheses at line 6 and didnt closed it.

```
print('hello world!')   
print('what is your name?')  #ask for their name
MyName = input()
print('It is good to meet you' + MyName)
print('The length of your name is: ')
print(len(MyName))
print('What is your age?') #ask for their age
MyAge = input()
print('You will be ' + str(int(MyAge) + 1) + ' in a year.')
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. I fixed it and now it runs correctly! Appreciate your help!